# Rotate Bing Maps

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am using bing maps in my app. I wanted to rotate the map in connection with the
rotation of the mobile, so that the maps always shows in the direction of the mobile. 
Is there a way to do this? I get information of the rotation from the compass, but i dont
know how i can rotate the map, so it rotates with the mobile.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to rotate the map within the Map control itself - however, if you really need to have the map rotate, you can use set the Map control's `RenderTransform` to a `RotateTransform`, and change the angle based on the reading from the compass.

The downside to this is that the performance will not be very good, and you will have to make the Map Control larger than the screen size, as when you rotate the control, the edges will show. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a possibility to draw a rotating compass on bing maps?